# How to correctly use a UserControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I created this user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="POS1.Windows.Controles.txttransparente"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="auto" Width=" auto"
             >


    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox  Name="txt1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Text="Usuario" FontSize="20" FontWeight="ExtraBold" ></TextBox>
    </Border>


</UserControl>
```

When I add it to a Window,

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:Custom="http://modernwpf"  xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"  
    x:Class="POS1.MainWindow"
    xmlns:txt="clr-namespace:POS1.Windows.Controles"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="292" Width="535"  AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" 
        >


    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="133*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="134*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="135*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="133*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border  Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="7" CornerRadius="40,50,60,70">
            <Border.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/b.jpg"/>
            </Border.Background>

        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBox   Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Text="Usuario" FontSize="20" FontWeight="ExtraBold" ></TextBox>
        </Border>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Contraseña" FontSize="20" FontWeight="ExtraBold" ></TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="5"  Grid.Column="1"  Content="Aceptar" FontSize="12" FontWeight="ExtraBold"  ></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="5"  Grid.Column="2"  Content="Olvidé contraseña" FontSize="12" FontWeight="ExtraBold"  ></Button>

        <txt:txttransparente Content=" Hola Mundo" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ></txt:txttransparente>



    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

as you see I could not modify the `txt1.Text`, so I have instead used `Content="hola mundo"`

[image]

However this sees it as above, but not as similar to the button **usuario**.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to change the text that is displayed in txt1? If so, just use a property on the user control to get/set the content of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicitly navigating the control's visual tree, the elements in your `UserControl` need for you to implement mechanism to pass data from client code using your control to the elements contained within. A common strategy for doing this is to simply declare a property on your `UserControl` type itself, and then bind the appropriate member in the control's tree to that property.

For example:

```
class txttransparente : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(txttransparente));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML for the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="POS1.Windows.Controles.txttransparente"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POS1.Windows.Controles"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="auto" Width=" auto">

    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"
            Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox  Name="txt1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="3"
                  Text="{Binding Text, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:
txttransparente}}}"
                  FontSize="20"
                  FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Note the change not only in the binding for the `TextBox.Text` property there, but also the addition of the `xmlns:local` declaration, so that the binding can find the parent `UserControl` object where the property exists.

These changes create the property, and connect it to the `Text` property of the control's `TextBox` element.

Then finally, where you use the `UserControl`, you simply set the `Text` property (instead of `Content`):

```
<txt:txttransparente Text="Hola Mundo" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```